# How to Pinch and Zoom an image using xaml in Windows8.1 store app?

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I have an image on my xaml Page.I want that user can Pinch and Zoom it using MouseWheel. I've tried with Scrollviewer many times but it is not working.This is what I am trying.                                                                                                                                `<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" Width="480" Height="270" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ZoomMode="Enabled" MinZoomFactor="0.7"> 
    <StackPanel Width="480" Height="270" Orientation="Horizontal"> 
      <Image AutomationProperties.Name="Image of a cliff" Source="images/cliff.jpg" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/> 
    </StackPanel> 
</ScrollViewer>`

Answer (score 0):

Default ScrollViewer should work with Control + MouseWheel.
And your code works.

Comment: It is working when I am running through Simulator.On my Desktop it is not working.